# Tar content without a specific directory

Tags: tar, magento

I have a magento installation I would like to tar. As some of you may now, in the root directory of a Magento installation is a directory called "media". This is the directory where all product images are stored.

I want to tar the entire Magento installation, without this directory. As this is not needed when developping, only on live server.

I have experienced with the --exclude option for tar, however, this excludes all directories called "media". I only want to skip the subdirectory media in the root.

Example root directory I want to tar:

/app
  /app/media -> I do not want to exclude this
/lib
/js
/media -> I want to exclude this
/skin
...etc

Normally I use tar -pcvzf filename.tar . to compress the whole directory. What would be the command to use to exclude the root media directory?

Answer (score 2):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984204/shell-command-to-tar-directory-excluding-certain-files-folders

The short version is that you can exclude the full path to the directory like so:

```
tar -pcvzf file.tar.gz --exclude=/media
```

Comment: This would be correct if I would like to exclude /app/media. But I want to exclude /media only. User302933 seems to be right.

Comment: Ah.  I was mistaken about what you did and did not want to include.  You probably should have put them on separate lines.  Assuming you wanted to exclude /lib, /js, and /media, you would want --exclude=/lib --exclude=/js --exclude=/media.  I edited my original answer to match the question.

Comment: Not really correct, as this will also exclude directories like /app/media. This is the whole problem. As said, User302933 has the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use anchors in the --exclude regex to limit the pattern matches.  If you do

```
tar -pcvzf filename.tgz --exclude "^media" .
```

that will exclude ./media but not ./app/media. The '^' at the beginning of the pattern

Comment: Did not think about using regex, but this should work. Thanks!